# get window width in NEXT.js without need to make every component client side

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have a website made with next.js that I wanted to work in mobile phones so I am trying to find out a way to get window size to render different components depending on which device it is rendering, so is there any way to get this result without actually have to convert every component that needs this functionality to client side ?

here is my custom useWindowSize hook -

```
'use client'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

function useWindowSize() {
  const isWindowClient = typeof window === 'object'

  const [windowSize, setWindowSize] = useState(
    isWindowClient ? window.innerWidth : undefined
  )

  useEffect(() => {
    function setSize() {
      setWindowSize(window.innerWidth)
    }
    setSize()
    if (isWindowClient) {
      window.addEventListener('resize', setSize)

      return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', setSize)
    }
  }, [isWindowClient, setWindowSize])

  return windowSize
}

export default useWindowSize
```

and for example here is my header component which is a server side component where I need this useWindowSize hook to get the window size -

```
import Link from 'next/link'
import styles from '@/app/page.module.scss'
import { getCategories } from '@/services'
import Image from 'next/image'
import SignInButton from '../buttons/SignInButton'
import ThemeToggleButton from '../buttons/ThemeToggleButton'
import useWindowSize from '@/utils/constants/useWindowSize'
import screenSize from '@/utils/constants/mediaQueries'

type Props = {}

async function Header({}: Props) {
  const { header, nav, logo, navLink } = styles
  const windowSize = useWindowSize()
  const categories = await getCategories()

  console.log(windowSize, screenSize.mobile)

  return (
    <header className={header}>
      <div className={logo}>
        <Link href="/">
          <Image
            src="/icons/hsb-icon.png"
            style={{ objectFit: 'cover' }}
            // sizes="(max-width: 768px) 40px, (max-width: 1200px) 50px, 40px"
            width={40}
            height={40}
            alt={'Logo'}
          />
          <span>Have Small Bytes</span>
        </Link>
      </div>
      <nav className={nav}>
        {categories.map((category) => (
          <Link
            key={category.slug}
            href={`category/${category.slug}`}
            className={navLink}
          >
            {category.name}
          </Link>
        ))}
        <ThemeToggleButton />
        <SignInButton />
      </nav>
    </header>
  )
}

export default Header
```

but unfortunately It gives the following error -

[image]